# Compare 2 nd columns from 2 files unix

Tags: unix, awk

Compare 2 nd columns from 2 files, unmatch match first file record s write into output file

Example:

@ delimiter

Filename_clientid.txt

```
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_4.xml@RIA00025
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_5.xml@RIA00024
RIA00026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA00026
```

Client_id.txt

```
ramesh@RIA000025
suresh@RIA000024
vamshi@RIA000027
```

Excepted output:

```
RIA00026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA00026
```

I used awk command  not working  can you help me

```
awk  -F '@' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} FNR==1 || !($1 in a)' Client_id.txt Filename_clientid.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix your example - you currently have 3 `0`s in each 2nd field per line in the first file and in the output but 4 `0`s in the second file when I assume they're supposed to all be 3 `0`s.

Comment: Why do you have `FNR==1 ||` in your code? Is there a header line in `Filename_clientid.txt` you want printed but you haven't shown in your example? If so, please [edit] your question to add that so your example accurately covers all your requirements.

Comment: From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142059/compare-2-nd-columns-from-2-files-unix#comment132610751_75142336) under one of the answers "I want output like this RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml not required second columns" - then [edit] your expected output to look like that rather than the whole line from `Filename_clientid.txt` as you currently show.

Comment: If added another row file1 not getting correct result   still giving one row
 RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA000067 –

Comment: It's not clear what that comment is referring to (your code? One of the answers? Something else?) but there's no reason at this point to add rows, just fix your example as I requested and then run the proposed solutions using it to see if they produce the corrected expected output from the corrected sample input or not. THEN if there's still an issue provide a comment about it. Right now we can't copy/paste your example to test with so everyone's guessing at what you want and making a comment about the effect of adding lines to an example that we can see is incorrect isn't useful.

Comment: [You edited one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75144031/revisions) to fix the sample input it contains - if you simply [edit] your question to do the same it'll greatly improve your question and help us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

alternative

```
$ join -t@ -j2 <(sort -t@ -k2 file1) <(sort -t@ -k2 file2)


RIA000026@RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@ramesh
```

Answer (score 1):

### With corrected inputs (was wrong with number of zeroes):

file1

```
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_4.xml@RIA00025
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_5.xml@RIA00024
RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA000026
```

file2

```
ramesh@RIA000025
suresh@RIA000024
vamshi@RIA000027
ramesh@RIA000026
```

### code

```
awk -F'@' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} $2 in a{print a[$2]}' file1 file2
```

### Output

```
RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml
```

Comment: working fine ,I want output like this   RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml  not required second columns

Comment: @sureshV then just change `a[$2]=$0` to `a[$2]=$1`.

Comment: If added another row  file 1 not getting  correct result  RIA000026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA000067

Answer (score 1):

The number of zeroes is not the same in both files. If they are the same, you can check that the field 2 value of *Filename_clientid.txt* does not occur in `a`

Filename_clientid.txt

```
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_4.xml@RIA00025
RIA00024_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_5.xml@RIA00024
RIA00026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA00026
```

Client_id.txt

```
ramesh@RIA00025
suresh@RIA00024
vamshi@RIA00027
```

Example

```
awk -F'@' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} !($2 in a)' Client_id.txt Filename_clientid.txt
```

Output

```
RIA00026_MA_plan_BTR_09282022_6.xml@RIA000026
```